# Why java doesn't support multiple inheritance, though all the java method are virtual by default?

Tags: java, diamond-problem

Why Java doesn't support multiple inheritance though all java method are virtual by default? Why diamond problem can arise in Java?

Comment: Only the people at Sun Microsystems can answer this question.

Comment: idea of removing multiple inheritance to remove complexity..

Comment: The issue (well, *one* of the issues) with multiple inheritance is name conflicts, it has nothing to do with methods being virtual by default.

Comment: As addendum to TJ said: do not confuse virtual _methods_ with C++ virtual _inheritance_.

Answer (score 5):

[James Gosling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Gosling) (known as the "father" of Java) said:

> JAVA omits many rarely used, poorly understood, confusing features of C++ that in our
>   experience bring more grief than beneﬁt. This primarily consists of operator overloading
>   (although it does have method overloading), **multiple inheritance**, and extensive automatic
>   coercions.

Reference: http://javapapers.com/core-java/why-multiple-inheritance-is-not-supported-in-java/

So according to him, they simply did not want to add it as they thought it was a bad idea.

P.S. Using multiple interfaces is NOT the same as multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

Diamond problem **cannot** arise in Java just because it's no possibility of a multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a sun's arbitrary decision to limit development errors resulting of multiple inheritance programming and romove complexity

Comment: Yes, which is known as the diamond problem, hence the question.

Answer (score 0):

Because Interface gives flexibility than concrete classes and we have option to implement multiple interface using single class. This is by agreement we are adhering to two blueprints to create a class. Lets see the pretty definition of java :

```
JAVA: A simple, object oriented, distributed, interpreted, robust, secure, 
architecture   neutral, portable, high performance, multithreaded, 
dynamic language.
```

Again there is no possibility of **Diamond problem** in java because it does not support *Multiple Inheritance.*